# Retrieve Address field for lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to display Contact MailingAddress field on a component.
On the soql in the controller I'm querying for :

```
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Name,MailingAddress  FROM Contact];
```

this results in an error in the request, checking on the javascript console there is :

```
"MailingAddress":*/{"message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 72942496-123091 (1722168560)"}/*ERROR*/
```

If I query for all fields in the compound Address it works fine.

this is the apex execution output :

```
38.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
07:15:22.0 (306737)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00541000001O7Im|andrea@lg-comp-dev.org|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-08:00
07:15:22.0 (326481)|EXECUTION_STARTED
07:15:22.0 (332688)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p4100000BhZV9|Contact_LTNG_Ctr.getContactsAndAddress
07:15:22.0 (607772)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
07:15:22.0 (648655)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
07:15:22.0 (665177)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
07:15:22.0 (679285)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
07:15:22.0 (692588)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
07:15:22.0 (718311)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
07:15:22.0 (731282)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:7
07:15:22.0 (741294)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p4100000BhZV9|Contact_LTNG_Ctr.Contact_LTNG_Ctr()
07:15:22.0 (744925)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
07:15:22.0 (751043)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
07:15:22.0 (782460)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
07:15:22.0 (804790)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
07:15:22.0 (810112)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
07:15:22.0 (824755)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
07:15:22.0 (837155)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5
07:15:22.0 (845427)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
07:15:22.0 (852434)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|Contact_LTNG_Ctr
07:15:22.0 (857567)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
07:15:22.0 (865680)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:5
07:15:22.0 (868191)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[11]
07:15:22.0 (869519)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[12]
07:15:22.0 (871750)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:44
07:15:22.0 (880947)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:4
07:15:22.0 (1802623)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[13]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Name, MailingAddress FROM Contact
07:15:22.0 (4093643)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[13]|Rows:21
07:15:22.0 (4108546)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:88
07:15:22.0 (4157651)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:1456
07:15:22.0 (4187675)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:88
07:15:22.0 (4197036)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[12]|contacts|List<Contact>|true|false
07:15:22.0 (4230536)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[12]|contacts|{"s":1,"v":"List of size 21 too large to display"}|0x7f28d514
07:15:22.0 (4233732)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
07:15:22.0 (4243359)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
07:15:22.4 (4264067)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
07:15:22.4 (4264067)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 21 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

07:15:22.4 (4264067)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

07:15:22.0 (4293608)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Contact_LTNG_Ctr.getContactsAndAddress
07:15:22.0 (6154291)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Does anyone know why the Address type fails within the lightning component ? Or if I should modify any setting on my environment?

thanks

Comment: Can you check your debug logs to see if there is any SFdC apex errors?

Comment: no apex errors that I could recognise. I added the log to the question body above.

Comment: MailingAddress is a compound field which, I suspect, is not supported in Lightning components. Try querying address details individually: `List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Name,MailingStreet, MailingCity  FROM Contact];`

Comment: hi @dhz, yeap querying for the fields individually the logic works fine. Wonder if there's a roadmap detailing when this type of fields will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query:

List contacts = [SELECT Id, Name,MailingStreet, MailingCity FROM Contact];

If you need complete address means please do concatenation and don't forgot to raise the case on salesforce...